# PyFPDF internal link

Tags: python, fpdf

How should internal linking be done? I try to link from page 1 to page 2. That works ok. But from page to page 2 doesn't work. What is wrong.

```
from fpdf import FPDF    
pdf = FPDF()

pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
to_page_2 = pdf.add_link()
pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Page 1', border=1, ln=0, align='', fill=False, link=to_page_2)

pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
pdf.set_link(to_page_2)
pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Page 2', border=1, ln=0, align='', fill=False)

pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
to_page_2 = pdf.add_link()
pdf.cell(40, 10, 'Page 3', border=1, ln=0, align='', fill=False, link=to_page_2)

pdf.output('pdf_link.pdf', 'F')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not set the destination of second link. `set_link` defines the page and position a link points to.

Add this line before you link the cell on page 3.

```
pdf.set_link(to_page_2, page=2)
```

In case you need more info on parameters you can pass to `set_link` check out the [the documentation](http://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/set_link/index.html).